# Facebook button fragment not opening and terminating the app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a fragment with facebook button. It worked for some times and now when I am trying to open the fragment using the navigation app drawer, it is crashing the app.

Below is the stack trace:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.myclass.myapp, PID: 3526
>                     java.lang.**NullPointerException**: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.**startTracking**()'
>   on a null object reference
>                             at com.myclass.myapp.FacebookLogin.onCreate(**FacebookLogin**.java:82)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2177)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1244)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:971)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:95)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2143)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
>                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>       Application terminated.

Code of fragment class:

```
    public class FacebookLogin extends Fragment {

    //initialize WebView
    private TextView mTextDetails;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        AccessTokenTracker tracker=new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

            }
        };

        ProfileTracker profileTracker=new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                displayWelcomeMessage(currentProfile);
            }
        };

        mTokenTracker.startTracking();
        mProfileTracker.startTracking();
  }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_login, container, false);
   }

   private void displayWelcomeMessage(Profile profile){
        if (profile != null){
            mTextDetails.setText(profile.getName());
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager,mCallback);

        mTextDetails = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile=Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code also... we wanna know what you did.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh. Updated the codes,, I used the application class to generate the hashkey...

Comment: check the below answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not initializing `mTokenTracker` in your onCreate()

```
 mTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            updateWithToken(newToken);
        }
    };
    mTokenTracker.startTracking();
```

also your `mProfileTracker` is not initialized

```
mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(com.facebook.Profile profile_old, com.facebook.Profile profile_new) {
                                        // profile2 is the new profile
                                        profile = profile_new;
                                        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                                    }
                                };
                                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
```